# How to integrate javascript to .volt template engine of phalcon php

Tags: javascript, php, phalcon

I need to use http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/ in my project which use framework PhalconPHP

In order to do so, my .volt file need to contain a javascript code like this

```
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %} //The problem begin here
 <tr class="template-upload fade">
  <td>
  <span class="preview"></span>
    ........//Some similar code here
  </td>
 </tr>
{% } %}
</script>
```

But the problem is {% and %} is .volt template syntax. When I use `{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}` like that, the .volt syntax and javascript syntax are conflict. Browser such as Chrome or Firefox will show the error : "Syntax error, unexpected token ( in /var/www/.... on line 77" where 77 is that line start with {%

In .phtml it works fine, but I don't want to rebuild my whole view template with .phtml
How can I use this code with .volt? Is there other syntax for javascript which is different from {% and %} ?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@jodator has a good approach.

Alternatively you can use PHP in your Volt template

```
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
<?php foreach (.....) { ?>
   <tr class="template-upload fade">
   <td>
       <span class="preview"></span>
       ........//Some similar code here
   </td>
   </tr>
 <?php } ?>
 </script>
```

The only issue here is that you have to be careful on what the scope of your variables are so that PHP can process them. For instance if `o.files` is a javascript object then you need to pass it as a variable in PHP. If it is a PHP object then all you will have to do is change it to `$o.files`

Comment: I think that the problem is with escaping Volt's delimiters in templates. Although your answer would be OK for server-side, the problem is in my opinion with collision of two templates mechanisms: one on server side (Volt) and the second one on client side (JavaScript template as in my answer). So the latter should be escaped (or changed) on server side.

Answer (score 2):

You can:

1. [Change javascript template syntax](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Templates#template-parsing) which this plugin uses.
2. [Use different templates](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Template-Engine) in jQuery File Upload
3. Echo strings which causes problems with volt ( `"{%", "%}", "{{", "}}"` ) :

```php
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
{{ '{%' }} for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { {{ '%}' }}
```

(3) is kinda messy but should work.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the template regex, per the Javascript Templates documentation:

To use different tags for the template syntax, override tmpl.regexp with a modified regular expression, by exchanging all occurrences of "{%" and "%}", e.g. with "[%" and "%]":

```
tmpl.regexp = /([\s'\\])(?!(?:[^[]|\[(?!%))*%\])|(?:\[%(=|#)([\s\S]+?)%\])|(\[%)|(%\])/g;
```

Check out the readme:
https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Templates#template-parsing

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for  jquery file upload plugin:

```
<!-- The template to display files available for upload -->
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
{{ '{%' }} for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { {{ '%}' }}
<tr class="template-upload fade">
    <td>
        <span class="preview"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p class="name">{{ "{%=" }} file.name {{ "%}" }}</p>
        <strong class="error text-danger"></strong>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p class="size">Processing...</p>
        <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0"><div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;"></div></div>
    </td>
    <td>
                {{ "{%" }} if (!i && !o.options.autoUpload) { {{ "%}" }}
            <button class="btn btn-primary start" disabled>
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                <span>Start</span>
            </button>
        {{ "{%" }} } {{ "%}" }}
    {{ "{%" }} if (!i) { {{ "%}" }}
            <button class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                <span>Cancel</span>
            </button>
    {{ "{%" }}  }  {{ "%}" }}
    </td>
</tr>
{{ '{%' }} } {{ '%}' }}
</script>

<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
{{ "{%" }} for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) {  {{ "%}" }}
<tr class="template-download fade">
    <td>
        <span class="preview">
                    {{ "{%" }} if (file.thumbnailUrl) { {{ "%}" }}
                <a href="{{'{%'}}=file.url{{'%}'}}" title="{{'{%'}}=file.name{{'%}'}}" download="{{'{%'}}=file.name{{'%}'}}" data-gallery><img src="{{'{%'}}=file.thumbnailUrl{{'%}'}}"></a>
        {{ "{%" }} } {{ "%}" }}
        </span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p class="name">
            {{ "{%" }} if (file.url) { {{ "%}"}}
                <a href="{{'{%='}}file.url{{'%}'}}" title="{{'{%='}}file.name{{'%}'}}" download="{{'{%='}}file.name{{'%}'}}" {{'{%='}}file.thumbnailUrl?'data-gallery':'' {{'%}'}}>{{'{%='}}file.name{{'%}'}}</a>
            {{ "{%"}} } else { {{ "%}"}}
                <span>{{ "{%="}}file.name{{ "%}"}}</span>
            {{ "{%"}} } {{ "%}"}}
        </p>
        {{ "{%"}} if (file.error) { {{ "%}"}}
            <div><span class="label label-danger">Error</span> {{"{%="}}file.error{{"%}"}}</div>
       {{ " {%"}} } {{ "%}"}}
    </td>
    <td>
        <span class="size">{{ "{%="}}o.formatFileSize(file.size){{ "%}"}}</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        {{ "{% if (file.deleteUrl) { %}"}}
            <button class="btn btn-danger delete" data-type="{{'{%='}}file.deleteType{{'%}'}}" data-url="{{'{%='}}file.deleteUrl{{'%}'}}" {{"{%"}} if (file.deleteWithCredentials) { {{ "%}" }} data-xhr-fields='{"withCredentials":true}' {{ "{%"}} } {{"%}" }}>
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                <span>Delete</span>
            </button>
            <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1" class="toggle">
        {{ "{% } else { %}"}}
            <button class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                <span>Cancel</span>
            </button>
        {{ "{% } %}"}}
    </td>
</tr>
{{ "{% } %}"}}
</script>
```