# Can't output scope variables angularjs

Tags: angularjs, phalcon

Here is my controller:

```
window.myApp.controller("WorkersController", ['$scope', function ($scope) {
$scope.people = ['1', '123', 'dog','qwewqe'];
$scope.input='';
$scope.add = function () {
    let index = $scope.people.indexOf( $scope.input);
    if ( $scope.input && index === -1) {
        $scope.people.push( $scope.input);
        $scope.update_layers();
        $scope.input = '';
    }
};
$scope.delete = function (item) {
    let index = $scope.people.indexOf(item);
    $scope.people.splice(item, 1);
    $scope.update_layers();
};
$scope.update_layers = function () {

};}]);
```

Here is my view:

```
<div id="p_Workers" ng-controller="WorkersController">
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-1 col-form-label">С</label>
    <div class="col-10">
        <input class="form-control" type="date">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-1 col-form-label">По</label>
    <div class="col-10">
        <input class="form-control" type="date">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <input id="add_worker" type="search" class="form-control col-9" ng-model='input' placeholder="Введите фамилию">
    <input class="form-control col-3" type="button" value="Add" ng-click="add()">
</div>
<div ng-repeat="man in people">
    {{man}}
    <input  type="button" value="X" ng-click="delete({{man}})">
</div>
```

I included angular and controller

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/WorkersController.js"></script>
```

And as result i get [this here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VbQU.png)

Can someone explain why ng-repeat doesn't show items in array?
It looks like my post is mostly code but code is the best details.

UPD: So I fixed my view and controller, so hope it will not distract you from ng-repeat.[maybe this can help somehow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rdh5f.png)

UPD2: Examples in plunker works good. But I forgot to say that I'm using phalcon. maybe there is some problems with volt?

UPD3: Volt problems.

Comment: if you got angular 1.5 or 1.6 try to change `people` to `$ctrl.people`, the controller itself must be named, anyway try to "kill" your scope :) 
https://daveceddia.com/convert-scope-to-controlleras/

Comment: What happens when you remove the col-3 from your button? What happens when you open the browser dev tools and inspect the DOM? It works fine here: http://plnkr.co/edit/GiDRxQTF9m2N9rR8R5mK

Comment: If i remove col-3 there are only small butoons left. Ye, I tried it on plunker too, and it works good.DOM has only inputs and no text before them,but $scope variable contain the values.`$ctrl.people` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.peoples` is not defined in your code. you have defined `$scope.people`. Change varible name as defined and it will work. Check https://plnkr.co/edit/0tDErSn6mcVhQhQPUfnM?p=preview

Comment: It's not the main problem, I just tried some ways to check my problem, and forgot to change it. The main problem is that there is no array items in ng-repeat. [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VbQU.png)

Comment: I tried your code with 1.3.15 and its working. check plunker link. Which angular version are you using? For that matter, it will not matter as its basic functionality in angular

Comment: I use version": "1.6.6"

Comment: Its working for 1.6.6 also. Check plunker link menstioned above in answer

Comment: I tried it on plunker too, but in my browser it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Works just fine for me if you disregard the fact that your functions don't work because you're referring to `$scope.people` as `$scope.peoples`.

**If all else fails you can try defining your $scope like this:**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('WorkersController', function() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.addWorker = "";
  vm.people = ['Леха', '123', 'Саня'];

  vm.add = function() {
    let index = vm.people.indexOf(vm.addWorker);
    if (vm.addWorker != "" && index === -1) {
      vm.people.push(vm.addWorker);
      vm.update_layers();
      vm.addWorker = "";
    }
  };
  vm.delete = function(item) {
    let index = vm.people.indexOf(item);
    vm.people.splice(item, 1);
    vm.update_layers();
  };
  vm.update_layers = function() {

  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="WorkersController as controller">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-1 col-form-label">С</label>
      <div class="col-10">
        <input class="form-control" type="date">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-1 col-form-label">По</label>
      <div class="col-10">
        <input class="form-control" type="date">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <input id="add_worker" type="search" class="form-control col-9" placeholder="Введите фамилию" ng-model="controller.addWorker">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="controller.add()">Add</button>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="man in controller.people">
      {{man}}
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="controller.delete(man)">X</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

`ng-repeat` creates its own scope inside of it. Using `ng-controller="X as controller"` you ensure that you can call upon your controller values within these newly created scopes using `controller.myFunction`.

Also note that it's considered good practice to give your input fields a model instead of getting their data via the way you're doing now. If you have buttons, try to actually use buttons instead of making inputs with as type button. The buttons themselves should have plenty of customization options for you to get what you want:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('WorkersController', function($scope) {
  $scope.addWorker = "";
  $scope.people = ['Леха', '123', 'Саня'];

  $scope.add = function() {
    let index = $scope.people.indexOf($scope.addWorker);
    if ($scope.addWorker != "" && index === -1) {
      $scope.people.push($scope.addWorker);
      $scope.update_layers();
      $scope.addWorker = "";
    }
  };
  $scope.delete = function(item) {
    let index = $scope.people.indexOf(item);
    $scope.people.splice(item, 1);
    $scope.update_layers();
  };
  $scope.update_layers = function() {

  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="WorkersController">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-xs-1 col-form-label">С</label>
        <div class="col-xs-11">
          <input class="form-control" type="date">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-xs-1 col-form-label">По</label>
        <div class="col-xs-11">
          <input class="form-control" type="date">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-xs-10">
          <input id="add_worker" type="search" class="form-control col-9" placeholder="Введите фамилию" ng-model="addWorker">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" type="button" ng-click="add()">Add</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" ng-repeat="man in people">
        <label class="col-xs-10">{{man}}</label>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" type="button" ng-click="delete(man)">X</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

---

**Edit:**

After reading your comments I'm quite convinced this is a matter of AngularJS's `{{}}` tags conflicting with Volt using the exact same notation.

This would lead to the conclussion that your code is correct from an AngularJS perspective and you need to solve the conflict between these frameworks. For this I suggest you take a look at the following links:

- [How to integrate javascript to .volt template engine of phalcon php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22829905/how-to-integrate-javascript-to-volt-template-engine-of-phalcon-php)
- [Changing Volt expression tags](https://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/811/changing-volt-expression-tags)

Comment: When I use controller as syntax nothing is shown, changing inputs to buttons doesn't change anything/

Comment: Using the `controller as` syntax only works if you also define a `var x = this;` in the controller. And you're right, it doesn't change anything, but it's considered good practice since input is meant to be input and a button-click isn't input, it's a button-click. It's just a matter of readability in case you shelf your code for a while and get back to it, or someone else uses it in the future. It also allows you to set custom styling for all the buttons in your project instead of having to create a custom class for it, if you'd so wish.

Comment: I tried to switch $scope to this but still no effect/

Comment: Then something might be wrong outside of the parameters you explained in your original post, as you can clearly see the snippets in the answers that have been given are working. You can try changing your ng-repeat to `ng-repeat="man in people track by $index"` and then adding `{{$index}}` just to check if there's something going wrong in the index selection, but I doubt it. (Output should be 0 - 1 - 2 - 3)

Comment: I can't do like this because I'm using phalcon. So Volt throw error because it think that {{$index}} is php variable.

Comment: In that case I reckon that that is the -exact- reason why your `{{man}}` is not showing anything while everything else is working. You may want to take a look at this link here: https://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/811/changing-volt-expression-tags & here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22829905/how-to-integrate-javascript-to-volt-template-engine-of-phalcon-php

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good practice to use getElementById method with angularjs. Instead use ng-model to retrieve data. and inside the function you have used the array incorrectly. (**$scope.people** and **$scope.peoples** are two different variables)
change code as below,

```
<input type="search" ng-model="worker" class="form-control col-9" 
placeholder="Введите фамилию">
```

change the function as below,

```
$scope.add = function () {
    var value = $scope.worker;
    var index = $scope.people.indexOf(value);
    if (value && index === -1) {
        $scope.people.push(value);
        $scope.update_layers();
        $scope.worker = '';
    }
};
```